# How to use JSON data in React

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I don't understand how to consume JSON data in React. My code:

```
  function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();
  const getImage = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api')
    .then(function (res) {
    setImage(res.data);
    })
   
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    getImage()
  }, [])`
```

Response:

```
{
    "title": "this is a title",
    "description": "",
    "tags": "",
    "isSorted": false,
    "passed": false
}
```

Error message:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, description, tags, isSorted, passed}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: add a console.log(res) to your .then callback function and post it here. Most likely you're trying to assign an object to your image instead of a string.

Comment: you likley have a problem in your rendering logic... Are you trying to render the JSON data directly

Comment: I understand that I'm passing an object. What am I supposed to do with this json object?

Comment: I am passing it to the state using setImage(). Is passing an object to state not allowed?

Comment: There's no JSON. The `res` passed to the `then` function off of the `axios` call is an object. JSON is a text format. That's why you get an error about objects not being valid React children, not an error about text not being valid React children.

Comment: Passing objects to state is allowed

Comment: What's happening is during initial render the data is not there, it fetches later. You have to take that into account while working with async data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
         setImages({title: 'Foo', description: 'Bar...'});
      }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return images ? <p>{images.title}</p> : <p>Loading images...</p>;
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

I think the problem is that you're trying to render the object instead of rendering each of the fields. Since I don't see your full `App` component implementation, I'll give you the best answer I can.

```
function Image(props) {
   return ( 
     <>
       <h1>{props.title}</h1>
       <p>{props.descriptio</p>
     </>
   );
}

function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();
  const getImage = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api')
    .then(function (res) {
    setImage(res.data);
    })
   
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    getImage()
  }, [])

  // This is assuming how your App component SHOULD look
  return (<Image image={image} />);
}
```

You are probably getting that error because you can't render the whole object, but instead, you have to render each field.

Your fetching logic however looks correct!

Comment: I should have included that, sorry.
```return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>{image}</p>
      </header>
    </div>```

Comment: If I try something like {image.title) it tells me that title is undefined.

Comment: That's  because during the initial render your data is not available yet, you're fetching the data in async fashion, because of useEffect().

Comment: What you have to do is add an IF to see if the data is available. Give me a sec, I'm creating a working example for you that you'll be able to implement :)

Comment: Ok, so what do I do? I just want to get the values of the object into the <p> element.

Comment: I know, you have to do something like this:

Comment: const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

return image ? <image image={image} : <p>Data is still loading</p>

Comment: Please allow me a minute to finish my example, then you'll see how it works

Comment: ```{image ? <p>{image.title}</p> : <p>loading...</p>}```

This worked, thank you dev-cyprium.

Comment: I've included an example code... Keep in mind, the reason you have to do it like that is because your component RENDERS BOTH when the images are NOT there, and again once they are there. So you need to have a case where you handle the state when the data is not available. usually that's when you render a spiner or something, in the example I just showed you "loading..."